# Gaming-related questions should be allowed on SU when they don't involve a specific game

Tags: feature-request

I understand that we don't want SU to become a "tips and tricks" site like GameFAQs. Some purely gaming-related questions, however, fit the scope of SU very well. Examples: "How important is the CPU for gaming?" or "Do games generally utilize multiple cores?"

Questions that are purely PC-related, and don't involve a specific game, should be allowed on SU.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No**

This opens a can of worms, because when gaming questions are asked and closed everyone points to these questions and immediately claim that we allowed them so why not these. The FAQ and Jeff has been quite clear on this, no gaming related questions, even if it is hardware. Both the questions you mention are also discussion topics which is also not allowed on the Trilogy and discouraged, since neither has a correct answer.

Furthermore there are already 2 or 3 gaming related stack exchange sites, which means SU can remains clean from these types of questions.

Comment: Well, let's keep that can tightly sealed then :)

Comment: If something can be learned from it, I think it should've be allowed or we have to help them rephrase it to be general enough to be allowed. Just keep away from CW questions

Comment: Ivo: Something can be learned from almost any topic, that doesn't make said topic *appropriate* for a specific site in the Trilogy.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a grey area where we should be too fast on closing them.

Once there was a question on proxy settings for Steam, which to me isn't really gaming related, since to me Steam is more like iTunes than it is to a specific game.

Though there are two stack exchange sites that might suit these needs, but I feel these don't draw the kind of audience that could solve these kind of problems.

So as long as the questions are general enough that they could be useful for common computer problems you can encouter with computer games, I don't see a real issue.

Comment: But you closed my question http://superuser.com/questions/121910/how-does-the-steam-platform-work-is-it-drm-can-i-trust-steam-powered-game ... hypocrite ;-)

Comment: I'm a jerk! Though I may not agree personally (I'm a gamer!) I don't make the rules all by myself and I do try to live by them ;-) @Basicallymoney.com

Answer (score 2):

**Ye... n.. sorta?**

We allow `What upgrade would be best for [non-gaming hobby]?`, but by it's nature, allowing game related versions would cause floods of <s>halfwits</s>people in need - however I think that currently the SU community is far too quick to close are purely gaming related. No, how do I pass level 2-2 of Super Mario is not a valid question (partially because it's *easy*), but I don't think a question should be closed just because the poster mentions a video game. Oftentimes these are perfectly valid questions, and would be given great answers, and not closed, without the reference. Questions such as "How do I overclock my processor?" are allowed, yet "How do I overclock my processor (for gaming)?" are not - they have the same answer (and as such closed as duplicate :P), and as such should not be closed.

I don't think gaming questions should be allowed at all (as diago says, can of worms - we allow one question, that's just inviting the hoards of gameFAQs users), but our definition of "**purely** console or videogame related" needs to be loosened up!